# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ given $\{ na_n\}$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis

I was trying to prove the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ given $\{ na_n\}$ is bounded.

All I could do was show that 
$$|na_n|\le M$$
$$|a_n|\le \frac{M}{n}$$ and hence the $n^{th}$ term goes to zero but this doesn't help.

Comment: Try with $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Good sign you do not succeed in proving this since this does not hold.

Comment: Now, the question is — *why* did you try to prove it? Was it a question of the type "prove or disprove" (and you tried the wrong one), or did you leave out some necessary assumptions by mistake?

Comment: Oh yes! It doesn't work. So I went in the wrong direction. My teacher asked me to show that the sequence of fourier coefficients $\{ na_n\}$ is bounded to conclude that the series converges uniformly. Any help with that? @DanielFischer

Comment: Perhaps they meant that the sequence $\{na_n\}$ converges to 0? Because that makes more sense.

Comment: @MeesdeVries It'd still be false, though.

Comment: Ah.  Hence the real analysis tag?

Comment: @ClementC., oops, of course, my bad. Perhaps that $\{n^2a_n\}$ is bounded then, but that seems less likely.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Maybe it;s not so unlikely since the OP mentioned Fourier coefficient and expressions related to $n^2$ are commonly found in the topic.

Comment: @MeesdeVries I think that is sufficient to show convergence.  (Not super familiar with fourier stuff)

Comment: Fourier coefficients? Of $e^{int}$, of $\cos (nt)$, or of $\sin (nt)$? If it's a Fourier sine series, check out the Dirichlet test. If $e^{int}$ or $\cos (nt)$, you still have problems at $2k\pi$.